# Remove columns the tidyeval way

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I would like to remove a vector of columns using dplyr >= 0.7

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

rem_cols <- c("wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
head(select(mtcars, !!paste0("-", rem_cols)))
```

> Error: Strings must match column names. Unknown columns: -wt, -qsec, -vs, -am, -gear, -carb

dplyr < 0.7 worked as follows:

```
head(select_(mtcars, .dots = paste0("-", rem_cols)))
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76
```

I've tried about all combinations of rlang:syms(), !!, !!!, quo and enquo that I can think of... help!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `one_of`

```
 mtcars %>%
        select(-one_of(rem_cols))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my specific question!

Comment: @PAC here the OP's input is string

Answer (score 6):

I would also use `one_of()` in this case but more generally you have to create calls to `-` with the symbols as argument.

```
# This creates a single call:
call("-", quote(a))

# This creates a list of calls:
syms(letters) %>% map(function(sym) call("-", sym))
```

You can then splice the list of calls with `!!!`

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful!

Comment: As of early 2018, `lang` is now deprecated according to the docs. Check out `rlang::call2`

Comment: Thanks, there's no reason to use call2 here so I switched it to base::call()

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty I had in doing precisely this task lead to me writing a package, [`friendlyeval`](https://github.com/milesmcbain/friendlyeval), to simplify the tidy eval API. Here's an idea on how to do this using that:

```
library(friendlyeval)
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

rem_cols <- c("wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
minus_cols <- paste0("-",rem_cols)
# [1] "-wt"   "-qsec" "-vs"   "-am"   "-gear" "-carb"

head(select(mtcars, !!!friendlyeval::treat_strings_as_exprs(minus_cols)))

#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76
```

The one trap here is that you must use `treat_strings_as_exprs()` instead of `treat_strings_as_cols()`, since "-wt" is an expression involving a column name, not an actual column name.

Answer (score 1):

```
drop = c("wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
 mtcars %>% 
    select_(.dots= setdiff(names(.),drop))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: It's for dplyr < 0.7