# Excluding rather than including gather variable using tidyeval tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse, tidyeval

If I wanted to exclude some columns (`Ozone`, `Day`, `Month`) that get "gathered" I can do this:

`tidyr::gather(airquality, key, value, -Ozone, -Day, -Month)`

But in a function, it isn't clear to me how to do this. This seems clumsy though it works:

```
my_gather <- function(col_to_compare) {
  gather_cols = dplyr::setdiff(c("Ozone", "Solar.R","Wind","Temp"), col_to_compare)
  tidyr::gather(airquality, key, value, !! rlang::enquo(gather_cols))
}

my_gather("Ozone")
```

Any idea how to exclude columns in a more rigorous way?

Note: This is with `tidyr` 0.7.0

Comment: Do you want a function that uses column names as strings?  If so, you might find `-one_of(cols_to_compare)` useful.

Comment: Do you want to pass the columns as something like `my_gather(Ozone)` rather than `my_gather(-Ozone)`? I think the latter is reasonably straightforward, the first one would be slightly more tricky.

Comment: aosmith is right that `one_of()` is the solution here.

Comment: Also you shouldn't use `enquo()` in this way (it shouldn't even work in that context, I think that's a bug). `enquo()` is for capturing an argument supplied by the user and wrap the captured expression in a quosure. Here there is no need to capture and it doesn't help to use a quosure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `gather()` has the same semantics as `select()`, this question is a duplicate of [Remove columns the tidyeval way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45100518/remove-columns-the-tidyeval-way/45145799#45145799).

You can use `-one_of(vars)` which is the recommended way to do it.

Alternatively you can construct a list of negated symbols and splice these expressions within the `gather()` call. Here is how to create symbols and wrap them in calls to `-`:

```
# This creates a list of symbols
syms <- syms(vars)

# This creates a list of calls:
exprs <- map(syms, function(sym) lang("-", sym))
```

You can then splice the list of calls with !!!:

```
df %>% gather(key, value, !!! exprs)
```